# Gravitino's and vielbein's gauge transformation in Freedman's Supergravity

Tags: gravity, gauge-invariance, supergravity

I'm facing a problem with Ex. 11.7 of Freedman's "Supergravity", specifically about gauge fields and their transformations. At page 218 the authors present a useful list of all structure constants for the gauged SUSY x Poincaré algebra.
Exercise 11.7 then asks to derive SUSY transformations of the vielbein and the gravitino. Now, using eq. 11.24 with A = a we get for the veilbein

$\delta_Q e^a_\mu = \bar\epsilon^\alpha\bar\psi_\mu^\beta f_{\beta\alpha}^a$

and the structure constant in the adjoint are just read from eq. 11.15

$\{Q_\alpha,Q_\beta\} = f_{\alpha\beta}^cP_c \equiv (Q_\alpha)_\beta^c P_c \implies f_{\alpha\beta}^c= -\dfrac{1}{2}(\gamma^c)_{\alpha\beta}$

which gives the correct solution if substituted.
Here I have the first issue: given that we are only considering SUSY transformations, why can't I also use $[Q_\alpha,M_{[ab]}]=\dfrac{1}{2}\gamma_{ab}Q = \dfrac{1}{2}(\gamma_{ab})_\alpha^\beta Q_\beta\;$ to get $\; f_{[ab]\alpha}^\beta=(Q_\alpha)_{[ab]}^\beta $ as the adjoint generator for such transformation?
In that case I would get

$\delta_Q e^a_\mu = \bar\epsilon^\alpha\bar\psi_\mu^\beta f_{[ab]\alpha}^\gamma$

which clearly is "index-inconsistent", but I don't see how can one avoid this circumstance.
Second of all, why does in the gravitino's transformation
$\delta_Q \psi_\mu$ it appears the spin-connection? The gauge field for SUSY is $\psi_\mu$, so I'd expect something like

$\delta_Q\bar\psi_\mu^\alpha = \partial_\mu\bar\epsilon^\alpha+\bar\epsilon^\beta\bar\psi_\mu^\gamma f_{\gamma\beta}^\alpha$

which is again ill with respect to the indices I should expect from the above construction of structure constants. The only way one can justify the presence of spin connection is to compute $\delta_\text{Lorentz}\bar\psi_\mu^\alpha$, but then again we are facing the same problem as before because one should also consider $[M,M]$ to find all the possible expressions for the structure constants.
I feel a bit lost, but thank you in advance!